# How to find how many rows beginning with a certain letter?

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I don't know how to find how rows begin with a certain letter in a data frame.

For example.

```
mtcars 
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt ... 
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.62 ... 
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.88 ... 
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.32 ...
```

I want to find out how many cars begins with the letter 'M'

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
sum(startsWith(rownames(mtcars), "M"))
# [1] 10
```

Other less efficient possibilities include

```
sum(grepl("^M", rownames(mtcars)))
# [1] 10
length(grep("^M", rownames(mtcars)))
# [1] 10
sum(regexpr("^M", rownames(mtcars)) == 1L)
# [1] 10
sum(substr(rownames(mtcars), 1, 1) == "M")
# [1] 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good way to do this is with stringr package

```
library(stringr)
str_view(rownames(mtcars),'^M') # to see all results or
str_view(rownames(mtcars),'^M', match = T) # to see only the match results
```